# Apache configure RedirectMatch arguments, add one to others

Tags: regex, apache

I need to transform an url like this:
/fr-ca/home.html?titi=toto to /fr/home.html?titi=toto&country=ca
And of course /fr-ca/home.htm /fr/home.html?country=ca

but it's always redirect to home, removing the page.

Where am I wrong?

```
    RedirectMatch 301 "^/([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})/(.*?)" "/$1/$3?country=$2"
    RedirectMatch 301 "^/([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})/(.*)" "/$1/$3&country=$2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` directive won't help here because you want new query parameter to be added in previous query string. This feature is only available using `QSA` flag in `mod_rewrite` module.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$1/$3?country=$2 [L,QSA,NC,R=301]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.